# Drawables in Assets

Tags: java, android, assets

There are several drawable folders in android. the **mdpi**, **hdpi**, **xhdpi** etc. 
So when I have a .png file for **mdpi**, **hdpi** etc. with the same filename but different resolutions, android will automatically pick the one that is best for my device, right?

I need to do the same with assets. I have a `LoaderScreen` class in my game which loads all the resources in the beginning I need into a skeleton class, so I can access them easily later in the game. However, I don't know how to place 2 pictures with the same filename but different resolutions in the assets so I can load them like that :

```
//returns the picture, myasset.png is the filename in the assets
loader.load( "myasset.png" )
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "I need to do the same with assets" -- why are they assets and not drawable resources?

Comment: @CommonsWare why would they?

Comment: Um, because they are drawables. If you want automatic density detection and resampling, that is what drawable resources are for. You're welcome to put PNG files in assets, but then you are on your own for everything: detecting the density of the device, choosing from some set of files based on your own naming convention, resampling the images if needed (beyond the scaling that might be applied for you by `ImageView`), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put them in assets, place them in the appropriate drawable folders.

If you need to access them programmatically you can get the drawable this way.

```
 context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myasset);
```

Comment: in most cases you do not need `context.getResources()` as you already in right context

Comment: Yes if you are in an activity you do not need context. But if he were to try to use that within his LoaderScreen he will likely need a context.

Comment: Well, noone knows what `LoaderScreen` really is, but I expect it to be just another activity. Anyway, your answer is not incorrect. I just added comment :)